# I can not do SerializeField and getting weird syntax errors in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to follow a tutorial where you need to be doing SerializeField to a moving car and add some variables. I am kinda familiar to C# syntax so I am almost 100% sure there is no syntax error in this code. What am I doing wrong here? I am getting

> error CS1001: Identifier expected

> error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Driver : MonoBehaviour
{
    float turningSpeed = 0.1f;
    float moveSpeed = 0,01f;
   
    void Start()
    {
      
    }

    void Update()
    {
     transform.Rotate(0, 0, turningSpeed);
     transform.Translate(0, moveSpeed, 0);
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLoEk.jpg
```

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing? Should that be a comma or a period? `float moveSpeed = 0,01f;`

Comment: Thank you, I actually was supposed to put a period there all along :(